# Battlefront: Is there a specific number of units active for each side?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront, star-wars-battlefront-2

At the end of each match in both Battlefront I and II, there is a listing of all the unit names and their accomplishments throughout the match.

Are *all* of these units active at any time during the match (assuming there are enough reinforcements to support them)? Or is there a smaller number actually active, with a waiting list (or something) of units waiting to spawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the units are active at once, and when they die, they use up a reinforcement to respawn. You probably figured this out by now, but that is the answer.